# How do I perform an 'every' query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a database with the a field of a document containing the following

```
new Test({fruits: [ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana']})
```

I want to query the fruits array by another array, making sure that the array passed into the query contains every item in the fruit database.

In plain JavaScript I would do the following:

```
var target = [ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana'];

var fruit2 = [ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'peach']; // true
var fruit3 = [ 'mango', 'lemon', 'pineapple']; // false
var fruit4 = [ 'banana', 'apple', 'orange']; // true

const result = target.every(targetElem => fruit2.includes(targetElem));
console.log(result);
```

I can't use `$in` because it goes through each item in the query array making sure all items exist. In my case, I don't mind if the queried array contains extra items, as long as it has the same ones as the array in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongodB version 3.6+, you could use `$expr` with `$map`, `$allElementsTrue`, and `$in` to evaluate each member of the array in each document against your query array.

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr:{
        $allElementsTrue:{
            $map:{
                input: "$fruits",
                in: {$in: ["$$this", [ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'peach']]}
            }
         }
    }
})
```

This will probably not be very efficient.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jav_ENWrOSo)

**Edit**:

An alternate way to do this that could use an index, at least in part:

```
db.collection.find({fruits:{$all:[ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'peach']}})
```

Comment: Thanks! Why will it not be efficient? Will it be slow? If so, what is a better way of doing it?

Comment: It will be inefficient because it will require reading every document from disk iterating each stored array in each document in order to find the matching documents.  No index can help with that.  I've edited an alternate solution into my answer

Comment: Are they both as quick and efficient?

Comment: The `$expr` form of that query will have to read every document in the collection in order to perform the comparison.  If there is an index on `{fruits:1}` the `$and` form of the query could use the index so it would only have to read all documents that have at least one of the elements in the query array, if that it significantly less than all documents, it might perform better.

Comment: forgot about the `$all` operator